# How to read stream encoding in uploaded text file in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, text

I have a web API that receives uploaded text files and parses them out, but they may be in different encodings.  I have this code to read the upload:

```
var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
using (var sr = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream(), true))
{
      textData = await sr.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I have this unit tested and I have sample files in Unicode and UTF-8 that the tests upload and it all parses out correctly.  However, when I upload to my Azure repository and it runs testing there (in Ubuntu) the tests fail and it's not getting the data right.  If I do it like this:

```
var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
using (var sr = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream(), Encoding.Unicode, true))
{
      textData = await sr.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

It works for the Unicode but not for UTF-8.  How to I get it to handle both?

Comment: Is it possible for the caller to explicitly state what the encoding will be in the http header? Or does the caller not know either...

Comment: If the caller does not know you will have to check the byte order marks in the stream header. Do a google search on how to do that, there are various articles and also [so] questions / answers that address this.

Comment: Client does not know either unfortunately (unless there is a way for javascipt/typescript/angular to detect that but I doubt it).  I guess I will be doing some research on byte order marks... thanks